# Locally installed spark history server is empty

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have installed spark 3.2.1 locally through homebrew and I wanted to see spark-history server.

Below is my sparks-defaults.conf.

```
 spark.eventLog.enabled true
 spark.eventLog.dir file:/tmp/spark-events
 spark.history.fs.logDirectory file:/tmp/spark-events
# spark.serializer org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
# spark.driver.memory             5g
# spark.executor.extraJavaOptions  -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Dkey=value -Dnumbers="one two three"
spark.history.fs.cleaner.enabled true
spark.history.fs.cleaner.interval 7d
spark.history.fs.cleaner.maxAge 15d
```

When I see in /tmp/spark-events, this is always blank. DO I need to enable anything else?

I am able to see Spark History server, but it is empty

```
http://localhost:18080/?showIncomplete=true
```